# How to open an Excel file on Excelize using URL link?

Tags: go

I tried to parse an Excel file and process it using Excelize. I only have a URL link that can be used to access the file.

For my case, I tested using a file I uploaded to Dropbox. The url from dropbox is like this `www.dropbox.com/s/t537135761/filename.xlsx`, but somehow when I try to use this link, the Excelize throws off this error:

```bash
open: www.dropbox.com/s/t537135761/filename.xlsx: no such file or directory
```

The file itself is already open for public. I can browse it on incognito mode so it means it's not because of restricted access problem. It has the extension file on the URL so I assume the URL touches the actual file that can be parsed by Excelize

I'm not sure if the problem is on Dropbox itself or is on Excelize, but that's only the cloud storage I can use to test my code.

Anyone can tell me how to use Excelize to open file using URL link? I tried searching for another function but can't find anything.

This is roughly my code (simplified) for testing.

```golang
package main

func main() {

var urlLink = "www.dropbox.com/s/t537135761/filename.xlsx"

exlz, err := excelize.OpenFile(urlLink)
if err != {
  fmt.Println(err)
  return
}

defer func() {
  if err = exlz.Close(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
}

  return
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution, below the explanation.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    excelize "github.com/xuri/excelize/v2"
)

func main() {

    // note here the 1 at the end instead of 0 in your original link
    openURL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ngoie6spyga8k1/for%20testing.xlsx?dl=1")
}

func openURL(urlLink string) {
    data, err := getData(urlLink)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Open the ZIP file with Excelize
    exlz, err := excelize.OpenReader(bytes.NewReader(data))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Reader", err)
        return
    }

    lst := exlz.GetSheetList()
    if len(lst) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Empty document")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Sheet list:")
    for _, s := range lst {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err = exlz.Close(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("Done")

}

func getData(url string) ([]byte, error) {

    r, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer r.Body.Close()

    return ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
}
```

For URL's you need to actually fetch the data first.

The second problem is that the Dropbox link that you used does not return an actual Excel, but an HTML file with an Excel embedded in it.

You need to change `dl=1` at the end. This will give you the actual Excel file.

Comment: I tried implementing this solution. But when I try to work on the excel file, it somehow doesn't read any sheet. It keeps saying `sheet is not exist` and when there's sheet, it reads nothing. Any idea why?

Comment: file is not available anymore. Can you put it back and I'll have a look at what's happening?

Comment: here's the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ngoie6spyga8k1/for%20testing.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: @newline can you try this new version? I tested and it works for me

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one works. Yeah, I didn't realize that it returned html, thought the xlsx extension on the URL would give me the actual file. But, there's something I'm confused, why does this one not need to be converted into zip? I tried not using zip previously, but there was an error that told me to use zip.

Comment: it turns out XLSX is a zip archive... Take your xlsx file and try to unzip it (on macos or linux: `unzip file.xlsx` otherwise rename it with zip extension and try to open it). When I posted the answer I didn't know that but I looked at the source code of the package and saw that it tries to unzip. Later today I also saw that it looks for specific file names inside the archive. And that made me think that xlsx might be an actual archive